# compare two strings (nul-terminated) other than doing it byte-by-byte?

Tags: string, algorithm, assembly, string-comparison

Like `strlen()` from glibc that performs a nice bit manipulation and 4 bytes checked per time making the function so fast, compared to a byte-by-byte routine as most all others do, is there something like this to compare two strings in assembly? I'm reading some pages on code implementation for C language, very interested in strings-handling part, but I still not found none like this.
I have to make this function as fast possible because it's the heart of my application.(don't recommend hash table)

Any assembler is welcome. But I'm a bit familiar with intel's assembly syntax, if assembly that you'll go to provide is different, please comment it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compare word by word (eg. 32-bits or 64-bits at a time). You just need to be careful not to go past the end of the string. If you are making the strings, then you could pad them with zeroes so they are a multiple of the word size, then you don't even need to check.

Comment: zeroes at end of string? ie "abcc",0,0 instead of "abcc",0?

Comment: Yes, zero bytes (NUL chars), so that the string length in bytes ends up being a multiple of four, or a multiple of eight if you're comparing 64-bit words at a time. This level of optimisation may not be necessary for most applications, of course :)

Comment: Any hint how to implement it in C? I aligned strings to 4 bytes with zeros but simple comparing doesn't work. The bytes are read in reverse order, abc0 like 0cba... Code sample: `unsigned int *s1 = (unsigned int*) str1; if (*s1 < *s2) return -1;`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming zero terminated strings (although the same applies for `memcmp()`); the fastest way to do string comparisons in assembly depends on the length/s of the strings, and the specific CPU.

In general; SSE or AVX has a high setup cost but gives faster throughput once it's running, which makes it the best choice if you're comparing very long strings (especially if most of the characters match).

Alternatively, something that does one byte at a time using general purpose registers will typically have a very low setup cost and lower throughput, which makes it the best choice if you're comparing lots of small strings (or even lots of large strings where the first few characters are likely to be different).

If you're doing this for a specific application, then you can determine the average number of characters compared and find the best approach for that average. You can also have different functions for different cases - e.g. implement a `strcmp_small()` and a `strcmp_large()` if there's a mixture.

Despite all this, if the performance of string comparisons matters a lot, then it's very likely that the fastest way to compare strings is not comparing strings at all. Basically, the words "*I have to make this function as fast possible because it's the heart of my application*" should make everyone wonder why better ways of implementing the application aren't possible.

Answer (score 3):

### StrCompCase (case sensitive) as implemented in [FreshLib/strlib.asm library.](http://fresh.flatassembler.net/index.cgi?page=content/related/0_FreshLib.txt)

Here is some code that uses dword comparison:

Note, that is first checks the length of the strings. That is because in the mentioned library the strings are length-prefixed, so StrLen is instant O(1) and scanning for termination NULL is provided only as a fall back (see the Second part of this answer).

Comparing lengths before actual comparison allows to make the speed O(1) for different strings, which in case of searching big arrays may significantly improve the performance.

Then the comparison goes on dwords, and, at the end, if the string length is not multiply of 4, the remaining 1..3 bytes are compared byte by byte.

```
proc StrCompCase, .str1, .str2
begin
        push    eax ecx esi edi

        mov     eax, [.str1]
        mov     ecx, [.str2]

        cmp     eax, ecx
        je      .equal

        test    eax, eax
        jz      .noteq

        test    ecx, ecx
        jz      .noteq

        stdcall StrLen, eax
        push    eax
        stdcall StrLen, ecx

        pop     ecx
        cmp     eax, ecx
        jne     .noteq

        stdcall StrPtr, [.str1]
        mov     esi,eax
        stdcall StrPtr, [.str2]
        mov     edi,eax

        mov     eax, ecx
        shr     ecx, 2
        repe cmpsd
        jne     .noteq
        mov     ecx, eax
        and     ecx, 3
        repe cmpsb
        jne     .noteq

.equal:
        stc
        pop     edi esi ecx eax
        return

.noteq:
        clc
        pop     edi esi ecx eax
        return
endp
```

### About StrLen code:

Here is the implementation of StrLen.

You can see, that if possible, it uses length prefixed strings, this way making the execution time O(1). If this is not possible it falls back into scanning algorithm that checks 8 bytes per cycle and it pretty fast, but still O(n).

```
proc StrLen, .hString    ; proc StrLen [hString]
begin
        mov     eax, [.hString]
        cmp     eax, $c0000000
        jb      .pointer

        stdcall StrPtr, eax
        jc      .error

        mov     eax, [eax+string.len]
        clc
        return

.error:
        xor     eax, eax
        stc
        return

.pointer:
        push    ecx edx esi edi

; align on dword
.byte1:
        test    eax, 3
        jz      .scan

        cmp     byte [eax], 0
        je      .found

        inc     eax
        jmp     .byte1

.scan:
        mov     ecx, [eax]
        mov     edx, [eax+4]

        lea     eax, [eax+8]

        lea     esi, [ecx-$01010101]
        lea     edi, [edx-$01010101]

        not     ecx
        not     edx

        and     esi, ecx
        and     edi, edx

        and     esi, $80808080
        and     edi, $80808080

        or      esi, edi
        jz      .scan

        sub     eax, 9

; byte 0 was found: so search by bytes.
.byteloop:
        lea     eax, [eax+1]
        cmp     byte [eax], 0
        jne     .byteloop

.found:
        sub     eax, [.hString]
        clc
        pop     edi esi edx ecx
        return
endp
```

Note that the zero terminated strings have both performance and security issues.

It is better to use size prefixed strings. For example, the mentioned library uses dynamic strings, where the string contains dword field at offset -4 (string.len in the above code) that contains the current length of the string.

Answer (score 3):

First rule for faster then byte-per-byte comparison is to malloc the strings or `.align 16` any constant strings to ensure

- robustness against security violations (reading past allocated area)
- best alignment for xxm (or 64-bit) processing